# If $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$, does $f'=0$ imply $f$ being constant?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

My question: Is the following claim true?

**Claim**. Suppose $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ and $f'=0$ on $\mathbb{R}$. Then $f$ is constant on $\mathbb{R}$.

I could prove a similar theorem for *open intervals* using the mean value theorem.

**Theorem** (*). Suppose $f$ is differentiable on $\left(a,b\right)$ and $f'=0$ on $\left(a,b\right)$. Then $f$ is constant on $\left(a,b\right)$.

My attempt: Suppose $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Then we can consider an open interval $I_{x}$ around $x$. Since $f'=0$ on $I_{x}$, by Theorem (*), $f$ is constant on $I_{x}$. Intuitively, the overlapping portion of $\left\{ I_{x}\mid x\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$  seems to enforce the constant being the same value. But I could not derive a rigorous discussion.

**Context**. I'm reading Spivak's Calculus (3rd ed). In Chapter 15, in the proof of the following lemma, the claim is used implicitly.

**Lemma**. Suppose $f$ has a second derivative everywhere and that $f''+f=0$, $f\left(0\right)=0$, and $f'\left(0\right)=0$. Then $f=0$.

*Proof (excerpted)*.
Multiplying both sides of the first equation by $f'$ yields $f'f''+ff'=0$. Thus $\left[\left(f'\right)^{2}+f^{2}\right]'=2\left(f'f''+ff'\right)=0$, **so $\left(f'\right)^{2}+f^{2}$ is a constant function** ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $f$ was not constant. Then we can find some $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ with $a<b$ such that $f(a)\neq f(b)$. But then, by the mean value theorem, there is some $\xi\in(a,b)$ such that

$$f'(\xi)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\neq0,$$

which is a contradiction. The result follows.

Answer (score 2):

As a corollary of your theorem, we can prove:

**Lemma:** If $I$ and $J$ are overlapping intervals in $\mathbb{R}$, and $f' \equiv 0$ on $I \cup J$, then $f$ is constant on $I \cup J$.

*Proof:* Take any $x \in I$, any $y \in J$, and any $z \in I \cap J$. By the theorem, $f$ is constant on $I$ so $f(x) = f(z)$. Similarly, $f$ is constant on $J$ so $f(y) = f(z)$. Thus, $f(x) = f(y)$, and since $x$ and $y$ were chosen arbitrarily, we may conclude that $f$ is constant on all of $I \cup J$. $\;\square$

This lemma generalizes to a countable union of overlapping intervals. Since we can find such a cover for $\mathbb{R}$, we may conclude that $f$ is constant on the entire real line.